# Motherboard was changed, Ubuntu does not reach internet

Tags: internet, motherboard

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 along with Win10 and the motherboard was upgraded. Win10 still reaches the internet, but on Ubuntu it stopped. I was reviewing many threads and solutions to similar problems but no avail.

`lshw -C network` outputs that:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
```

and does not provide logical names

`ip address show` outputs:

```
1: lo: ...
```

and no other (sorry, I am not sure how to include full outputs as there is no internet.)

I also tried to edit `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethetnets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
```

but I could not figure out what logical name to give instead of `enp0s3` as suggested at another thread.

Many thanks for suggestions.

Comment: can you try ifconfig in the terminal and see what is the output? also is this a dualboot system?

Comment: Please check in windows what hardware it is exactly

Comment: Thanx @nobody, I checked in Windows. It is Realtek PCIe 2.5GbE Family Controller. I could not run ifconfig (@Fat Krow), it is not installed, and now I cannot install anything new. It is dualboot, indeed.

Comment: Are you sure the hardware is supported in Ubuntu 18.04? If it's a new generation MB, then maybe you need HWE (hardware enablement kernels) for the network adapter to be working.

Comment: How does one find out whether the motherboard is supported in 18.04? And, excuse my ignorance, could you direct me to info on HWE's? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the most likely solution is that the device name is wrong in the netplan file:

You can get the logical name of the interface with one of these commands: `ip link show` or `ifconfig`.

Now, identify the correct name, and replace `enp0s3` in your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file with the new name.

After this, you can run:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

If everything works as expected, you should now have network access.

Comment: I tried a liveUSB and the internet worked fine. I checked the logical name there, it was enp3s0 so I changed in my netcfg. I applied the changes to netplan but the internet is still not working. I will probably upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.